# 32-bit rollover with time() in 2038

Tags: c++, time

A lot of C++ programs are written with the `time()` function, but as you probably know, this is not going to work after the year 2038 as it will return a negative integer. It's going to cause a lot of programs to be completely unusable, so I'm just wondering, what is going to be the solution, and is anybody worried about this? Is there actually an alternative out there right now?

Also, do you think this is going to be a major problem or is not something really to worry about?

Comment: Use [`<chrono>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) instead of [`<ctime>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time)

Comment: God help me if I am still around in a professional level, supporting code from today :)

Comment: `time_t` has been widened to 64 bits on 64 bits machine for a couple years now. Only 32 bits machine should experience the bug. Will there still be 32 bits machines by 2038?

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae *"Will there still be 32 bits machines by 2038?"* Of course! And they'll still be running IE6 I'm sure :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Haha so you're taking the "not my problem" approach yeah? Lol

Comment: There are still important programs running that were written in COBOL. I'm sure something somewhere will explode in 2038 and be a major problem for somebody.

Comment: To the people voting to close: I don't see how this is *primarily* opinion based or too broad. It has a pretty specific answer.

Comment: @David To me at least, `"do you think this is going to be a major problem or is not something really to worry about?"` is a question that is formulated to ask for people's opinion (keywords: `"do you think"`).

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae I have multiple questions in here, some opinion based, some very objective.

Comment: Pretty much every platform has its own relatively standard alternative to the C standard library's `time_t` if you are really paranoid. You often wind up using them anyway if you want something with greater resolution than 1 second.

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae True, but I still don't really think the question is *primarily* opinion based. The main part of the question is regarding a fact, not an opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One question is answerable:

> Is there actually an alternative out there right now?

Yes, since C++11 the `std::chrono` library provides time types that are specified to be good for roughly 500 years. Since they're nicely encapsulated, it shouldn't be too difficult to extend their range, if anything recognisable as C++ is still in use by then.

On most modern platforms, `time_t` has 64 bits, so even using that the problem can be avoided if you're careful to always assign the results to `time_t` variables, not `int` or whatever.

The other questions are purely speculative. I suspect the problem will be similar to Y2K - most programs will already do the right thing; others can be easily changed; and there will be some ancient systems churning away long after the developers have retired, the compilers discontinued, and the source code lost.

Answer (score 1):

The [`time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time) function returns a [`time_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time_t) value and it's not specified how big the `time_t` type must be. Implementations will probably just change the `time_t` `typedef` so that it is at least 64 bits in size. I think this is already the case on most (or all) 64-bit machines. There is a chance that this could cause a problem for programs that depend on `time_t` being less than 64-bits, but I imagine that's very unlikely to often be the case for something like `time_t`.

Comment: That's all well and good, but how much code do you think looks like `unsigned x = time(NULL);`?

Comment: @Barry That could be a problem, but it depends on the size of `unsigned` on that architecture. If it is a problem, it can be fixed by changing to `time_t`.

Comment: @DavidYoung: "Changing to `time_t`" might not be entirely trivial, if that's buried in a million lines of 50-year-old legacy code. There was plenty of code like that before Y2K, and I'm sure there'll be plenty more next time.

Comment: @MikeSeymour That's very true, but I never said it would necessarily be easy. As far as I know, that's the only solution. Anything else I can think of would involve even more work.